# Concatenate tag values that occur in arbitrary order (XSLT)

Tags: xslt

I am converting an XML document for which I concatenate the values of two tags:

```
  <xsl:variable name="label">
    <xsl:value-of select="label"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="nr">
    <xsl:value-of select="nr"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="label_nr">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($label, ' ', $nr)"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

This works for

```
  <label>Article</label>
  <nr>1</nr>
```

But I want the following

```
  <nr>First</nr>
  <label>article</label>
```

To generate 'First article', instead of 'article First'. Is there an easy way to distinguish the order of tags in XSLT?

Comment: Just so you know, you do not need any of the variables. Instead you can just do `<xsl:value-of select="concat(label, ' ', nr)"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To mke things even simpler, try

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat((nr | label)[1], ' ', (nr | label)[2])"/>
```

This concatenates the first and the second element of the element set `(nr | label)`.

Note that `(nr | label)` is exactly the same as `(label | nr)`. The order of the elements in your set is determined by the order of the elements in your XML.

Because the original order of the elements is preserved in this set, `[1]` will select the first element and `[2]` the second element in your tree.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use axes to do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="label_nr">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name(nr/following-sibling::node()[1]) = 'label'"><xsl:value-of select="concat($nr, ' ', $label)"/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="concat($label, ' ', $nr)"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

`nr/following-sibling::node()[1]` is selecting the next node on from the `nr` node. We need the [1] as the axis `following-sibling::` will fetch all following nodes, so `[1]` just gets us the next one along. We then just use `name()` to get the name of the element. Hopefully it's clear what's going on from there.

Comment: Nice! Do you know what happens if `nr/following::node()` is empty? Will the test just return false, or will it throw an index out of bounds exception?

Comment: Ah - buggette in my answer (now fixed). You actually want to use `following-sibling::`. `following::` walks the tree to the next node, regardless of the level of that node (so if the node /a/b/c is at the end of an /a/b branch and there's another /a/b branch, following:: will take you to b. `following-sibling::` ensure that it's only nodes *at the same level*. In this instance, if a node doesn't exist, you get an empty node, and name() returns an empty string.

Comment: As an addendum to that - there's a nice pictorial view on the different axes at http://www.xmlplease.com/axis ... pictures describe each axis better than I could ever do in words.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0, use

```
<xsl:value-of select="label|nr"/>
```

That's all.

Comment: Does `value-of` of an element set implicitly concatenate all values with a space inbetween?